# Using Jacobi's formula with matrix equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I have a system

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\begin{bmatrix}\hat a(\omega,z) \\ \hat b(\omega,z) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \Delta_1 & \Delta_2 \\ \Delta_3 & \Delta_4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\hat a(\omega,z) \\ \hat b(\omega,z)\end{bmatrix} = H_{\omega}\begin{bmatrix}\hat a(\omega,z) \\ \hat b(\omega,z)\end{bmatrix}.$$

I can transform the two-point boundary-value problem into an IVP by introducing, for each frequency $\omega$, the propagator $P_{\omega}$, satisfying

$$\frac{d}{dz}P_{\omega}(0,z) = H_{\omega} P_{\omega}(0,z).$$

I can then write from the linearity of the ODE system:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\begin{bmatrix}\hat a(\omega,z) \\ \hat b(\omega,z) \end{bmatrix} = P_{\omega}(0,z)\begin{bmatrix}\hat a(\omega,0) \\ \hat b(\omega,0)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Jacobi's formula then says

$$\frac{d \det(P_{\omega})}{dz} = \text{Tr} \, (H_{\omega}) \det\,(P_{\omega}).$$

If the trace of $H_{\omega}$ is zero then it is simple to see that the determinant of $P_{\omega}$ is constant in $z$, and the value is given by an initial condition.

However, for a more complicated system, (that I'm trying to solve), the trace of $H_{\omega}$ is not zero. Can I then say anything about the determinant of $P_{\omega}$?